# Why does a grouped struct.pack write wrong data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

I just spent ~30 minutes debugging and double checking Python & C# code, to find out that my struct.pack was writing the wrong data. When I separated this into separate  calls, it works fine.

This is what I had before

```
file.write(struct.pack("fffHf", kf_time / frame_divisor, kf_in_tangent, kf_out_tangent, kf_interpolation_type, kf_value))
```

This is what I have now

```
file.write(struct.pack("f", kf_time / frame_divisor))
file.write(struct.pack("f", kf_in_tangent))
file.write(struct.pack("f", kf_out_tangent))
file.write(struct.pack("H", kf_interpolation_type))
file.write(struct.pack("f", kf_value))
```

Why does the first variation not write the data that I expected? What is so different than writing these separately?

(File is opened in binary mode, platform is 64 bit Windows, Python 3.5)

Comment: can you provide a MCVE? _https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve_

Comment: What platform are you on?  Is this Python 2 or 3?  Did you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: 64 bit Windows. Python 3.5. File is opened in Binary mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably because, as the `struct` documentation clearly states:

> **Note** By default, the result of packing a given C struct 
>       includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment 
>       for the C types involved; similarly, alignment is taken 
>       into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so 
>       that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to 
>       the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To 
>       handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit 
>       pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of 
>       native size and alignment: see [Byte Order, Size, and 
>       Alignment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) for details.

Comment: Yep, that's the reason.  You should add a `=`, `<` or `>` at the beginning of the format string, depending on the endianness you want.

Comment: Here I was thinking the "</!/>/=" only meant endianness, and had no effect other than that. Thanks!